# Локализация изображений  в iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Стоит задача загружать соответствующее изображение фона на view в зависимости от выбранного языка локализации. То есть во -viewDidLoad контроллера нужно оформить схему

```
    if (выбран русский)  {
     [self setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageWithImage:@"ru.png"]];
} else if (выбран английский)  {
     [self setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageWithImage:@"en.png"]];
}
```

То есть как узнать значение выбранного языка?

Comment: [Статья по локализации приложений][1].


  [1]: http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/03/16/lokalizaciya-ios-prilozhenij/

Comment: В статье нет ничего по локализации изображений. Apple вообще не рекомендует так делать прописывая весь текст программно, но в моем случае будет готовый дизайн и приложение не будет релизиться в аппстор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вариант хороший, но я делал чуть иначе, правда это касалось не языков, а цветовых схем.

Суть такая.

Добавляете категорию на UIImage

```
@interface UIImage (LocalizedImage)

+ (UIImage *)localizedImageWithName:(NSString *)aName;

@end

@implementation UIImage (LocalizedImage)

+ (UIImage *)localizedImageWithName:(NSString *)aName {
    NSString *localeId = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
    return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png", aName, localeId]];
}

@end
```

Теперь все что от вас требуется, это иметь в бандле картинки именованные соответствующе, к примеру:

```
background_en.png

background_ru.png
```

З.Ы. мог ошибиться в синтаксисе, пишу по памяти.

Comment: Я так понимаю что перед этим необходимо добавить в проект localized.strings необходимых языков?

Comment: Не, строки это для строк. Просто подставляете нужные картинки и все.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду имплементить!

Answer (score 0):

Так вроде ж можно просто в Xcode локализовать саму картинку и программа автоматически загрузит нужную картинку в зависимости от языка.

Comment: а как ее локализовать?